# How can I make Python read the first value from a xlsx file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, csv

I've been trying to read a list for a project, in which I have to calculate some values, but the problem is that I can't manage to read all values properly.

The Excel file, has the following values:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
3.3
```

But when I use the pd.read_excel(excel) function, it considers the 1 as a title for a table, so it ends up reading and saving this:

```
    1
0   2.0
1   3.0
2   4.0
3   5.0
4   6.0
5   7.0
6   8.0
7   9.0
8  10.0
9   3.3
```

It should not have a title, so I need to find a way to read all values from the top to the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force read_excel to not read headers.  Here is an excerpt from the documentation:

> header : int, list of int, default 0 Row (0-indexed) to use for the
>   column labels of the parsed DataFrame. If a list of integers is passed
>   those row positions will be combined into a MultiIndex. Use None if
>   there is no header.

So you could go :

```
pd.read_excel(excel, header=None)
```